# generic http service reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm new learner to reactjs and i want make some service to interact with api, i want make the http service more generic so it can be used in other components.
you can see the code

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CanceledError } from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/",
});

export { CanceledError };
```

first i create baseURL for the API calling, and i make a generic http service that contain method2 like get, post and put

```
import apiClient from "./api-client";

interface Entity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class HttpServices {
  endpoint: string;
  constructor(endpoint: string) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
  }
  getAll<T>() {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const request = apiClient.get<T[]>(this.endpoint, {
      signal: controller.signal,
    });
    return { request, cancel: () => controller.abort() };
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    return apiClient.delete(this.endpoint + "/" + id);
  }

  add<T>(entity: T) {
    return apiClient.post(this.endpoint, entity);
  }

  update<T extends Entity>(updatedEntity: T) {
    return apiClient.patch(
      this.endpoint + "/" + updatedEntity.id,
      updatedEntity
    );
  }
}

//export default new HttpServices();

const create = (endpoint: string) => new HttpServices(endpoint);

export default create;
```

and then i used the generic http service to work with user and put users endpoint

```
 import create from "./http-service";
export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export default create("users");
```

and i use the user service in form update user component

```
const updateUser = (users: User) => {
    const originalUser = [...user];
    const updatedUser = { ...users, name: users.name + "!" };
    setUsers(user.map((u) => (u.id === users.id ? updatedUser : u)));

    userServices.update(updatedUser).catch((err) => {
      setErrors(err.message);
      setUsers(originalUser);
    });
  };
```

hope you guys understand my explanation

SO, the question is ...

if you see in generic http service is use interface Entity to extend generic place holder data type that contain id and name which is same as user interface in user service, what if i want make category service with category interface with id, name and description ? if I add description in Entity interface that showing error when i used in updateUser method "Argument of type '{ name: string; id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Entity'."
how can i make that interface more flexible or acceptable ? or any suggestion with that ?

i just want to know that solution of my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this solutions:

- Firstly, in the base `HttpService` you need to fully-satisfy axios built-in types to make your base service more flexible.
- Secondly, you need to create some `ApiServiceFactory` that will be instantiating your entity-specific services like `UserService`, `AuthService` or `CategoryService` with different axios settings like `headers` or `baseUrl`.
- If your entities urls have same starting path (as it often), you can hardcode starting path in base class `constructor` (`{baseUrl: 'https://myapi.com/${baseUrl}'}`). And then `ApiServiceFactory('user')` will instantiate axios with `baseUrl: 'https://myapi.com/user'`; And `ApiServiceFactory('category')` lead to axios with `baseUrl: 'https://myapi.com/category'` and so on.
- But if your entities urls don't have same starting path, for example, `User` relates to `https://api1.com/user` and `Category` relates to `https://someotherapi.com/v1/en/category`. You need to stay `baseUrl` in base `HttpService` constructor to empty and specify full url in factory with `CategoryService extends ApiServiceFactory('https://someotherapi.com/v1/en/category')`
- Thirdly, you need to specify certain(concrete) types only in entity-specific service, in my example it is `User`, `UpdateUser`, `Category`, `CreateCategory`, `ManyId`, `Record<SignUpFieldsEnum, string>`, `Record<SignInFieldsEnum, string>`.

Base `ApiService` class:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import type { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
# ... List of imports my own types ....

export class ApiService {
  api: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(baseUrl = '') {
    this.api = axios.create({
      baseURL: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${baseUrl}`,
    });
  }

  protected async get<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const { data } = await this.api.get<T>(url, config);
    return data;
  }

  protected async put<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const { data: d } = await this.api.put<T>(url, data, config);
    return d;
  }

  protected async post<T = any>(url: string, data?: any, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const { data: d } = await this.api.post<T>(url, data, config);
    return d;
  }

  protected async delete<T = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<T> {
    const { data } = await this.api.delete<T>(url, config);
    return data;
  }
}
```

Class `UserService`:

```js
class UserService extends ApiServiceFactory('user') {
  profile(): Promise<User> {
    return this.get<User>('');
  }

  update(data: Partial<UpdateUser>): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.put<boolean>('');
  }
}
```

`AuthService` class:

```js
class AuthService extends ApiServiceFactory('auth') {
  signIn(data: Record<SignInFieldsEnum, string>): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.put<boolean>('sign-in', data);
  }

  signUp(data: Record<SignUpFieldsEnum, string>): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.post<boolean>('sign-up', data);
  }

  logout(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.put<boolean>('logout');
  }
}
```

`CategoryService` class:

```js
class CategoryService extends ApiServiceFactory('category') {
  async list(params: PaginationQuery): Promise<Paginated<Category>> {
    return this.get<Paginated<Category>>('', { params });
  }

  create(data: CreateCategory): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.post<boolean>('', data);
  }

  update(id: number, data: CreateCategory): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.put<boolean>(`/${id}`, data);
  }

  remove(data: ManyId): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.delete<boolean>('', { data });
  }
}
```